# How to alter secondary database in high availability group?

Tags: sql-server

I want to run an alter database command (change the owner) but being part of the HA Group, the database is in read-only mode. I changed the primary so I am guessing I have to force a failover and then update it? Is there a simple way to unjoin or suspend (looks like suspend keeps the read only mode turned on), make the change, and then join it back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database owner detail is stored in the master.sys.sysdatabases table, and not on the user database. So when you run the statement on the primary database, it will not transfer to the secondary database.

Changing the database owner requires a read-write database. 
try failing over to the secondary database and make it as new primary database, and then change the database owner of new secondary database. then switch back to primary

Reference: [Perform a Planned Manual Failover of an Availability Group (SQL Server)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231018.aspx)

Regards,
Suing

Comment: Well, i guess confirming my thoughts and saying there isn't a way is an answer. :(